# is there a way to change the localhost port to 8888?

Tags: phpstorm

When using the browswer preview option in PHPStorm, I get to:

```
http://localhost:63342/projectName
```

Is there a way to configure that to be:

```
http://localhost:8888/projectName ?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For PhpStorm **v8.0.1** and older: **Settings | Debugger**

For PhpStorm **v8.0.2** and newer: **Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger**

[image]

Comment: Would never think of looking under debugger. I did a search/filter for "localhost" and similar words but nothing came up. Thank you!

Comment: I can't change its value, it puts the original value back automaticaly....

Comment: @naspy971 How exactly it does that. It seems to work just fine here. Can you record some small screencast? -- maybe there are some nuances in the way you do it...